# get image height from drawable at ArrayAdapter class

Tags: android, image, get, height

i try to make my image view position dynamic base on image height. but i stuck to get the image height from drawable.. help me to solve it thanks..

this is my code :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_wall, null, true);
        TextView txtProfileUser = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtWallProfile);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtWallContentTitle);
        TextView txtContent = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtWallContent);
        ImageView imgWallProfile = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivWallProfile);
        ImageView imgWallContent = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivWallContent);

        txtTitle.setText(web2[position]);
        txtContent.setText(web3[position]);
        txtProfileUser.setText(web[position]);
        imgWallProfile.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        imgWallContent.setImageResource(imageId2[position]);


        GetSize gz = new GetSize();
        Integer h = gz.getImageSize(imageId[position]);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(20,h, 0, 0);
        imgWallProfile.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return rowView;
    }
```

and this my getImageSize method :

```
public Integer getImageSize(Integer d){
    Drawable bd = getResources().getDrawable(d);
    int height=bd.getIntrinsicHeight();
    return height;}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem / question ?

Comment: try this `BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
int height=bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to get the width and height of your image view instead of the bitmaps width and height. Layout parameters allows you to access the imageView and view and modify it's parameters.

```
public int getImageSize(View myView) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
    return myParams.height;
}
```